# Disabling Hot Reload for .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Some time ago, a Visual Studio update added a hot reload feature.  It be handy, but it also can be annoying especially when you're testing and you don't want to reset the current state of the front end.  Visual Studio injects the script whether you're debugging or not.

How can hot reload be disabled? My Visual Studio version is 16.10.3

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/speed-up-your-dotnet-and-cplusplus-development-with-hot-reload-in-visual-studio-2022/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change this feature here:

`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > ASP.NET Core > Auto build and refresh option`

> Options to automatically build and refresh the browser if the web server is running when changes are made to the project.

Your options in this dropdown are the following:

1. None
2. Auto build on browser request (IIS only)
3. Refresh browser after build
4. Auto build and refresh browser after saving changes

Also note my version of VS is `16.11.1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this option so I may have to update.

Comment: I set it to none and even after restarting visual studio it continued to add /_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js to the bottom of my index.html. Maddening.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this setting has no effect even in VS 2022 RTM. Microsoft continues to deny the problem in this support thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-disable-hot-reload-for-aspnet-core-projects/1506697?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1578834

I ended up adding a rule to uBlock to block this - under "My filters", add "\*aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js\*" (no quotes)

Comment: This suggestion is just plain wrong. It is for control if hot reload is NOT set elswehere

Answer (score 10):

In VS2022, unchecking the "Enable Hot Reload" setting under the projects Debug Properties disables the injection of the `aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js` script.

These screenshots show one way to access the setting:

[image: Visual Studio debug menu]

[image: Visual Studio debug profile]

Comment: Unfortunately this disables .NET hot reload entirely, which is a bit of a heavy-handed approach to preventing the unwanted JS file from being injected into HTML responses.

Comment: Perhaps heavy-handed in some circumstances, but exactly what I needed to make YARP happy when CSP was being applied (this symptom: Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:50071/IdentityServer/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.)

Comment: Can you give some directions instead of a picture? How did you get to Launch Profiles? "Debug" tab at top -> Open your "<my app> Debug Properties" at the bottom of the popup. Mine doesn't have these settings.

Comment: just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

With the CLI you have to do

```
dotnet watch --no-hot-reload
```

Answer (score 8):

in VS 2022 open launchSettings.json in the Properties folder

find your profile and add (see arrow, don't add arrow)

````
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Gang.Bingo.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7249;http://localhost:5249",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "hotReloadEnabled": false   <===========
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Any idea how to do this for `dotnet watch run`? The command seems to ignore that, still goes "Hot reload enabled" on startup too.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller see my answer

Comment: This works without having to disable Hot Reload entirely for all projects.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a great solution, but it's a viable workaround.

In the "Network" tab of Chromium Edge's developer tools, I found the request to load `aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js`.  I right click on it and selected "Block URL".  This prevents the script from loading.

Comment: If you're using uBlock, you can also add a filter (under "My filters" in its settings): "\*aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js\*" (without quotes)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, go to
**Tools > Options > Debugging > General**

and check this option ***Enable edit and continue and hot reload***

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to disable both Hot Reload and Edit and Continue.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me (VS 2022 17.7.0)