# .NET 6.0 Blazor Server Side "WebSocket connection to '' failed:" (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I was excited to use the Blazor on .NET 6.0 when the Visual Studio 2022, so I tried to create a Blazor Server Side application with stylesheet and javascript that I used on my previous Blazor Server project, however, I encounter this error.

***"WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:9895/MyProject/' failed: "***

I thought it was a bug that the VS team needs to fix, so I wait for an update when they release **17.1.2(3/22/2022)**, the problem still persists.

then I found this post: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/WebSocket-connection-to-wss:-fail/1670519?q=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&ftype=problem&space=8&stateGroup=active&sort=newest

and notice that there are people who are the same as me, that still encounter this error, does everyone also experience this? or there is a workaround for this?

I hope someone can help me because I excited to use the .NET 6.0 version of Blazor Server Side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952259/disabling-hot-reload-for-net-core-project-in-visual-studio-2019