# Disable ASP.NET Core hot reload script from frontend

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages, hot-reload, asp.net-core-7.0

Sometimes I make changes in my IDE and don't want the page to be reloaded in the browser after I save. A typical scenario is that I make changes to the page via the devtools, and if the page is reloaded then those changes would be lost; or perhaps I'm interacting with some remote API and don't want to lose such state.

There [are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68952259/9971404) to disable hot reload, but that's not what I want - I want to keep using it, but to disable it per page, on demand, from the frontend itself. For example, I want to inject a button into the page with a script that disables hot reload.

The `_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js` script is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/release/7.0.2xx/src/BuiltInTools/BrowserRefresh/WebSocketScriptInjection.js).

The obvious solution is to clear the script's timeout, but it uses `setTimeout` without saving the id.

I tried this without success:

```js
window['_dotnet_watch_ws_injected'] = 1;
```

What else could I try?

Comment: I added a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54107) to the repo to save the timer id for easy cancellation - **please upvote it if you also need this functionality**. In the mean time, I hope there is some workaround.

Comment: You can try to see a request to load `aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js` in the "Network" tab of the Chromium Edge developer tools.Then select it and select Block URL. This will prevent the script from page loading.

Comment: @YuningDuan Thanks, that would work, but I need a programmatic way to stop it so it can be easily done via a script. Also it would be a bother to turn on and off all the time, as I only want to disable it sometimes.